# How can I programmatically find a list of all Shortcut keys assigned in C# Winform?

Tags: c#, winforms, keyboard-shortcuts

How can I programmatically get a list of shortcut keys that are used in my app?  I have a winform with many menus and menu items (including dynamically generated menu items) having assigned shortcut keys.

Really having a hard time keeping track of all the shortcut keys and thought it would be nice to display a list to the user.

Comment: Even if you could do this (and I cant think of a reliable way to achieve it) It would likely take longer to write this than it would to just go through every form and audit

Comment: You can use `SendInput` method and try in loop.

Comment: Have you tried enumerating the menu items and extracting their ShortcutKey properties, and deciding the values (awkward, because its flags, but doable because it's all part of the Keys enum). Note, you didn't say certainly that you're using ToolStripMenuItem but I would also point out that if you are, and have set the ShortcutKeyDisplayString property on each, you could use that if it's just for displaying a list to the user

Comment: @CaiusJard in specific i was thinking of the toolstrip menu, wasn't sure if shortcut keys exist elsewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see several problems in your requirement:

- For `File-New` you have to type `<alt-F> <alt-N>`; for `Edit-Names` you need to type `<Alt-E> <Alt-N>`
- Therefore `<Alt-N>` is not enough in your shortcut collection, You need the full combination: `<alt-F> <alt-N>` for menu File-New, and `<Alt-E> <Alt-N>` for Edit-Names
- What if the designer forgot to add the `<alt-F>` in the file part and the `<alt-E>` in the edit part? Then you would have two `<alt-N>` shortcuts!
- Short-cuts also work on other controls, like Buttons
- What about the standard shortcuts like `<Ctrl-C>` and `<Ctrl-V>`?

Let's assume your shortcuts are unique, you only want shortcuts for menu items and you want them from the root menu. Alas, class `System.Windows.Forms.Shortcut` doesn't have values for `<Alt-..>` shortcuts, so we'll just remember the shortcuts as uppercase characters: so "FN" means `<alt-F> <alt-N>"`

You need to iterate each menu item with all sub-menu items, and check if the `Text` property contains an ampersand.

I'll do this as extension methods for `MenuStrip` and `ToolStripItem`. A menu strip has the main menu's as ToolStripItems in property `Items`; a ToolStripItem has the sub menu's in property `DropDownItems`.

If you are not familiar with extension methods see [extension methods demystified](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2013/03/08/c.net-little-wonders-extension-methods-demystified.aspx)

First the class to put the results:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
class ShortCut
{
    public string ShortcutSequence {get; set;} = String.Empty;
    ToolStripItem ToolStripItem {get; set;}
}
```

Get the ShortCut of a ToolStripMenuItem or Default if it has no shortcut:

```
public static char GetShortcutCharOrDefault(this ToolStripMenuItem menuItem)
{
    // Return the character after the ampersand in property Text,
    // or null if there is no such thing
    return menuItem?.Text?.SkipWhile(c => c != '&') // skip until &
        .Skip(1)                                    // skip the &
        .Select(c => char.ToUpper(c))               // make the char uppercase
        .FirstOrDefault()                           // char after the ampersand
        ?? default(char);                           // or default char if no text
}
```

From a sequence of ToolStripMenuItems to a sequence of Shortcuts.

```
public static IEnumerable<Shortcut> ToShortcuts(
    this IEnumerable<ToolStripMenuItem> menuItems,
    string parentShortcutSequence)
{
    // TODO: handle invalid input

    foreach (var menuItem in menuItems)
    {
        char shortcutCar = menuItem.GetShortcutChar();
        if (shortCutChar != default(char))
        {
           // This menuItem has a shortcut.
           var shortcut = new ShortCut
           {
               ShortcutSequence = parentShortcutSequence + shortcutChar,
               ToolstripItem = menuItem,
           }

           // return this shortcut
           yield return shortcut;

           // and check for the shortcuts of the sub menu items
           // recursively!
           var subShortcuts = menuItem.Items.ToShortcuts(shortcut.ShortcutSequence);
           foreach (var subShortcut in subShortcuts)
           {
               yield return subShortCut);
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
MenuStrip mainMenuStrip = ...
IEnumerable<ToolStripItem> menus = mainMenuStrip.Items.Cast<ToolStripItem>();
IEnumerable<Shortcut> shortcuts = menus.ToShortCusts(String.Empty);
```